# Tkinter Widgets without Parent Master

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-label

What are the consequences when omitting the parent master of a widget? Those two programs do not produce a visual difference:

```
import tkinter as t
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

w = t.Tk()
w.title("Label 1")

label_1 = ttk.Label(text="Label")
label_1.grid(row=0, column=0)

fenster.mainloop()
```

vs.

```
import tkinter as t
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

w = t.Tk()
w.title("Label 1")

label_1 = ttk.Label(w, text="Label")
label_1.grid(row=0, column=0)

fenster.mainloop()
```

Comment: Widget without specifying the master will use the first instance of `Tk()` as the master, that is why the two examples have same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you ommit the master option it will use the root widget.
Which is the Tk() instance or in Tkinter the root widget '.'

You can get parent with **winfo_parent()** methode.

```
import tkinter as t
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

w = t.Tk()
w.title("Label 1")

label_1 = ttk.Label(text="Label")
label_1.grid(row=0, column=0)
print("parent =", label_1.winfo_parent())
w.mainloop()
```

Output:

```
parent = .
```